# Moving File in IsolatedStorage Not Permitted Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I grabbed this directly from the msdn skydrive page. Performing a download and when it finishes as it suggests moving the file out of the shared/transfers folder. I am doing this in a background thread.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  if (isoStore.FileExists(App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName))
  {
     isoStore.DeleteFile(App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName);
  }
  try
  {
     isoStore.MoveFile(@"shared/transfers/" + App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName, "test.mp3");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```

The file is there, even if I filled in garbage paths that don't exist it still throws `Operation Not Permitted on the iso.Store.MoveFile`

test.mp3 does not exist either in the root.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to move file that is opened or used by other thread?

Comment: Why you checking for App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName in the root and then moving same App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName from the /shared/transfers/?

Comment: Because thats where Im moving it too, if it already exists then delete it.

Comment: I thought the file might be in use except if I change the source file name to something that doesn't exit I get operation not permitted still.

Comment: Show us the code after download and how you detect that download is done.

Comment: await liveClient.BackgroundDownloadAsync(App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).Id + "/content", new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + App.ViewModel.DownloadQueue.ElementAt(i).FileName, UriKind.Relative), ctsDownload.Token, progressHandler);

Comment: It is awaited so the thread only continues when the download completes. You can see the location it is saved to as well.

Comment: And you move file is in the same thread? Just behind downloading?